# Typescript TSC CommandLine - Prevent TSC from watching

Tags: tsc

At first: I know the difference between `tsc` and `tsc -w` in the command line. This is not the problem, it's rather a special situation:

In the tsconfig in VS Code I enabled the watcher by setting `"watch":true`. This is absolutely wanted. But now the problem:

I have some scripts that should install the whole VS Code project environment (so the specific project itself) and want the project initially be compiled by tsc. But now it compiles it in watch mode, since the tsconfig says to do so. Could I make an exception here? When initially compiling in the bat file I want that tsc does not automatically set the watch option to true, but compile it while igoring if the watching option in tsconfig is on or off.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: please, which is the difference between tsc and tsc -w ?

Comment: -w is a parameter standing for "watch", which means that the tsc compiler will keep open after compiler your code and whenever a ts-file inside your project changes, the compiler will automatically re-compile the project files, so that your project is up to date. Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks @jlang, but you know why in new tutorial angular2 , script start run twice tsc:  tsc and tsc -w, when i active log, they compile twice; i find no send: "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ", look at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: @stackdave Sorry for the late answer, but no – unfortunately I don't have a clue why they seem to run tsc twice. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do better than a renaming-based solution. Right now, the problem is that when you invoke `tsc`, the `-w` (`--watch`) flag is overridden by `compilerOptions.watch` value specified in your `tsconfig.json` (located in the same directory as the `tsc` script is invoked in). We'll be using a feature introduced in TypeScript 2.1: [configuration inheritance](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#configuration-inheritance).

## Base config, `tsconfig.json` (one-off mode)

Write whatever the typical behaviour should be here. This will be our base (default) `tsconfig` file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "watch": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true
  }
}
```

## Extension config `tsconfig_w.json` (watch mode)

Now we write an extension for it, wherein a single property is changes: `compilerOptions.watch` is overridden to `true`.

```
{   
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "watch": true
    }
}
```

## Command-line invocation of `tsc`

Before, you were invoking `tsc` without providing any further arguments. Now, you should specify explicitly which `tsconfig` it should read from.

- One-off: `tsc --project tsconfig.json` (this is the default file it'll use, but let's be explicit).
- Watch: `tsc --project tsconfig_w.json`

*Note: the `--project` flag was introduced in [TypeScript 1.8](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5858#issuecomment-161031270).*

## Optional extra for convenience: `package.json`

I tend to write these as convenient scripts into my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "lib": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc  --project tsconfig.json",
    "libw": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc --project tsconfig_w.json"
}
```

You would then simply run `npm run lib` or `npm run libw` depending on which script you needed.

*Note: I've specified the path to TypeScript locally rather than globally (as I haven't installed it globally).*

Comment: Marked your answer as correct, as it is certainly the better way of doing it.

Comment: And maybe add `"$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig"` to the extended `tsconfig.json` to make it have autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by simply using the rename command of windows:

```
rem Rename the tsconfig to prevent the tsc-task from watching
rename "tsconfig.json" "temp-hide.json"
rename "setup-config.json" "tsconfig.json"
tsc
rem Undo renaming since the task finished
rename "tsconfig.json" "setup-config.json"
rename "temp-hide.json" "tsconfig.json"
```

In my installation process, I renamed the tsconfig.json to temp-hide.json (since the tsconfig contains the option watch)
and then renamed a setup-config.json to tsconfig.json, so that this file 
is used instead.

When all files have been renamed I finally execute the command tsc, and
after that command executed, I rename everything back to their original
file names.